# Умножение матриц (статических и динамических)

Tags: c++, массивы

Нужно создать метод для умножения двух матриц, но чтоб он [метод] был похож как для динамических, так и для статических матриц. Чтобы матрицы передавались в него в качестве аргументов, а не были бы заданы константно.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
//#define row 3
//#define colum 8
//#define k 3

void Multiplication(int row, int colum, int k, int **aMatrix, int **bMatrix, int **product)
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < row; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){                        
                    // Обнуляем элемент,  в который будет производится 
                    // запись перемножения строки на столбец
                    // product[i][j] = 0;
                    for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++)
                    {
                        // Записываем сумму, умножая поочередно элементы строки и столбца
                        product[i][j] += aMatrix[i][z] * bMatrix[z][j];
                    }
                    std::cout << product[i][j] << " ";
                }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }

int main()
{
    int k = 3, row = 3, colum = 8;
    int **a1Matrix, **b1Matrix, **product1;
    product1 = new int*[k];
    a1Matrix = new int* [row];
    std::cout << "Enter elements matrix A: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) { // ввод рандомом
        a1Matrix[i] = new int[row];
        for (int j = 0; j < colum; j++){
            a1Matrix[i] = new int[colum];
            //std::cin >> a1Matrix[i][j];
            a1Matrix[i][j] = rand() % 5;
            std::cout << " " <<a1Matrix[i][j];

        } 
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    b1Matrix = new int*[colum];
    std::cout << "Enter elements matris B: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < colum; i++) {
        b1Matrix[i] = new int[colum];
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            b1Matrix[i] = new int[k];
            //std::cin >> b1Matrix[i][j];
            b1Matrix[i][j] = rand() % 5;
            std::cout << " " << b1Matrix[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    Multiplication(k, colum, row, a1Matrix, b1Matrix, product1);

    std::cout << "A * B = \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n row " << (i + 1) << ":";
        //product1[i] = new int[k];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            //product1[j] = new int[k];

            std::cout << product1[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        delete product1[i];
    delete[] product1;

    //return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это нельзя сделать. Можно, конечно, динамически выделять одномерный массив с общим числом элементов, соответствующих двумерному массиву, но в таком случае вы не сможете обращаться к нему, используя два индекса. Поэтому затея вашего преподавателя не понятна. То есть это неизбежно, что каждый метод будет иметь свое тело, и не будет общего вызываемого кода..

Comment: Если бы это можно было сделать, то не было бы необходимости объявлять два метода.:) Достаточно было объявить один метод. Поэтому вам придется создать два отдельных метода: один шаблонный, а другой, который вы уже пытаетесь написать.

Comment: Вообще звучит как перегрузка методов, на мой взгляд. Не этого от вас хотят?

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу несколько вариантов.
*Вариант 1*. Перегрузка функций. У вас будет две функции с разными параметрами, но одинаковым именем.
*Вариант 2.* Шаблонная функция.
*Вариант 3.* Класс-оболочка для матрицы - абстрактный класс для доступа к элементам матрицы, и наследники для статической и динамической матрицы. Произведение реализуется опосредованно через эту оболочку.

Не следует забывать, что динамическую матрицу можно реализовать двумя способами - как массив указателей на массивы строк, и как единый одномерный массив с соответствующим обращением к элементам.

Выбирайте :) Когда выберите - можно будет заняться реализацией.

Answer (score 0):

статическую матрицу тоже можно подавать в качестве аргумента: указатель на матрицу и её размеры
например, вот так

```
multiply(double *A, int Ax, int Ay, double *B, int Bx, int By)
```